# PL/SQL: How can I write this program?

Tags: plsql

I have 3 Columns: 'GAME' 'PLAYER_ID' 'MINUTES_PLAYED'

looks like this:

```
GAME     ID     MINUTES_PLAYED
12550788  229569   23
12500788  393438   4
12500788  458730   25
12500782  229569   10
```

I would like find total minutes played per game i.e.

```
ID       TOTAL_MINUTES
229569   33
.
.
.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add them up:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(MINUTES_PLAYED) AS TOTAL_MINUTES
FROM table GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`select id, sum(minutes_played) from tableName group by id`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(MINUTES_PLAYED)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY ID
```